# Unclosed character class using punctuation in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to build a regex pattern that'll remove punctuations from a string. I've decided to use `punctuation` from the `string` library. However, when I execute it, Spark returns an error that theres an unenclosed character.

I suspect the characters within `punctuation` closes up a quote during execution. I have a feeling that this should be simple to fix but I'm not sure how. My code is below:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import regexp_replace, trim, col, lower
import string

def removePunctuation(column):

    no_punct = regexp_replace(column, string.punctuation, '')
    lowered = lower(no_punct)
    cleaned = strip(lowered)
    return cleaned
```

And I get this error `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 86.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 86.0 (TID 3709, localhost): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 31`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Plain and simple:

```
regexp_replace(column, "\p{Punct}", "")
```

To use `string.punctuation` you'd have to escape individual characters and put them in a character set but it is error prone and ugly:

```
import re

regexp_replace(column, "[{0}]".format(re.escape(string.punctuation)), "")
```

Comment: Man that was great. Where did you find that \p{Punct} ?

Answer (score 3):

```
column = regexp_replace(column, '[^\w\s]', '')
column = regexp_replace(column, '_', '')
```

Note that underscores are treated as legitimate alphanumeric characters, so need special removal.

Answer (score 0):

you might just include things you want: digits, letters and spaces

```
return lower(trim(regexp_replace(regexp_replace(column, '[^\w\s]', ''),'_','')))
```